# Start Countdown on Resuming Game (Unity)

Tags: unity, timer

I am pausing game by setting Time.timeScale to 0. And When the Game resumes Time.timeScale is set to 1f again, and game resumes. Now I want to add timer before actually resuming game. It shows 3,2,1,Go and player starts running. But problem is that It is not counting as Time.timeScale is set to zero. And if i set Time.timeScale to 1, the player starts running immidiately and countdown also starts perallaly. Actually I want to start countdown first and then to resume game. I've added the code below, that i've used. The game and timer both is activated perallally by following code.

```
IEnumerator WaitToResumeGame()
{   
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);
        TimerText.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "" + i;
    }
    TimerText.SetActive (false);
}

public void ResumeGame()
{
    pausePanel.SetActive (false);
    TimerText.SetActive (true);
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    StartCoroutine (WaitToResumeGame ());
}
```

Comment: Check out [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/3-2-1-countdown-on-resume-the-game.205138/#post-1386920) link

Comment: I think this is what your looking for : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-unscaledDeltaTime.html

Comment: The problem is solved out using Time.realtimeSinceStartup [Example](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/117495/start-countdown-on-resuming-game-unity/117499?noredirect=1#comment206411_117499)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a little trick for that:

use the `Time.realtimeSinsceStartup` property

when you end the pause set a variable like

```
float endPause = Time.realtimeSinceStartup + 3; //for 3 Seconds countdown
```

and right after that:

```
while (Time.realtimeSinceStartup < endPause){
     yield return 0;
}
Time.timeScale = 1;
```

That will cause the game to wait another 3 seconds before continuing. Of course you need to modify it a little to display a countdown but that shouldn't be a problem for you.

Comment: As I'm new to Unity, I can not adjust that. Can you please help me. Your code helps me to freeze game for 3 second, But it starts countdown after that 3 second, means game and countdown starts perallaly.

Comment: Currently I'm at work so I don't have time to give you an example. I'll provide you one when I'm at home.

Answer (score 1):

`yield return new WaitForSeconds` is very much affected by `timeScale`. So if `timeScale` is zero, that coroutine will never continue.

Jonas' answer is correct, but I'd like to add something you may find helpful: in Unity 5, you can write a class that does the same thing as `WaitForSeconds`, but with unscaled seconds instead of scaled. This is the class I use:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class WaitForRealSeconds : CustomYieldInstruction
{
    private float m_FinishTime;

    public WaitForRealSeconds(float seconds)
    {
        m_FinishTime = seconds + Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
    }

    public override bool keepWaiting
    {
        get
        {
            return m_FinishTime > Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point! I also thouth about that but I thought it would become to complex, but I was wrong :) +1 from me

Comment: @JonasWirth It was a bit more complicated before Unity introduced `CustomYieldInstruction`. It was still possible, but not with the `yield return new WaitXXX()` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use WaitForSecondsRealtime on the place of WaitForSeconds. It will work.

Comment: This answer would be even better if it included a little explanation of how this differs from WaitForSeconds and how it solves the problem. (As-is, it flagged our auto-moderation systems for being so short )

Answer (score 0):

The following code helps me to do both, Countdown and after that to resume game.

```
IEnumerator WaitToGetReady()
{
    TimerText.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "" + 3;
    yield return WaitToResumeGame ();

    TimerText.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "" + 2;
    yield return WaitToResumeGame ();

    TimerText.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "" + 1;
    yield return WaitToResumeGame ();

    Time.timeScale = 1f;

    TimerText.SetActive (false);
}

IEnumerator WaitToResumeGame()
{   
    float start = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
    while (Time.realtimeSinceStartup < start + 1f) {
        yield return 0;
    }
}

public void ResumeGame()
{
    pausePanel.SetActive (false);
    TimerText.SetActive (true);
    StartCoroutine (WaitToGetReady ());
}
```